# Top DIV size to content - bottom DIV scrolling and fit remaining space to window

Tags: html, css

I want to have two divs below each other. The top one should have a height depending on its content. The bottom one should fill the remaining space to the window border and if the bottom content is too large, it should be scrollable.

I have a working solution https://jsfiddle.net/3cm3vvv7/1/

```css
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
        }

        body {
            padding: 0px;
            margin:0px;
            height:100%;
        }
        
    .red {
        background-color: red;
    }
    
    .green {
     background-color: green;
    }
    
    .blue {
     background-color: blue;
    }
    
    .purple {
     background-color: purple;
    }
    

  .container {
      display: block; 
      height: 100%;
        }

        .table {
            display: table;
            width: 100%;
            height:100%;
        }

        .row {
            display: table-row;
            width: 100%;
        }
        
        .row-scrolling {
         display: table-row;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            position: relative;
            
        }
        
          .inner-table {
            
      width: 100%;
            height: 100%;

        }

        .header-cell {
            display: table-cell;
            padding: 5px;
            height: 10%;
        }
        
        .scroll-cell {
            display: table-cell;
            padding: 5px;
            position:relative;
         height: 100%;
        }
        
        
     .scroll-content {
         position: absolute; 
         top: 0px; 
         right:0px; 
         bottom: 0px; 
         left: 0px;
         overflow-y: scroll; 
         height:100%;
        }
```

```html
<body>

        <div class="table" >
            <!-- Header -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="header-cell">
                    Header<br/>.<br/>.<br/>.<br/>.<br/>.<br/>.<br/>.<br/>.<br/>.<br/>.<br/>.<br/>END
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row-scrolling " style="background-color: red;">
                        <div class="scroll-cell" >
                            <!-- Use inner div's with position relative and absolute, to fix cell height,
                                 making it overflow correctly. -->
                                <div class="scroll-content">
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                    <div>Some text.</div>
                                </div>
                       
                        </div>
            </div>
            <!-- footer -->
        </div>
</body>
```

but it only seems to work fine for Safari/Firefox - on Internet Explorer the content of the bottom is truncated.

I would prefer a solution with HTML/CSS only, so no JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify that code all the way down to this, here using `flexbox` instead of `table`.

The beauty with this is also its fallback for older browsers, where they get a nice full page scroll.

```css
html, body {
   margin: 0;
 }
 .wrapper {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   height: 100vh;
 }
 .row-scrolling {
   flex: 1;
   overflow: auto;
 }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="row">
    Header
    <br/><br/><br/>
    <br/><br/><br/>
    <br/>END
  </div>
  <div class="row-scrolling " style="background-color: red;">
    <div>Some text</div><div>Some text</div>
    <div>Some text</div><div>Some text</div>
    <div>Some text</div><div>Some text</div>
    <div>Some text</div><div>Some text</div>
    <div>Some text</div><div>Some text</div>
    <div>Some text</div><div>Some text</div>
    <div>Some text</div><div>Some text</div>
    <div>Some text</div><div>Some text</div>
    <div>Some text</div><div>Some text</div>
    <div>Some text</div><div>Some text</div>
    <div>Some text</div><div>Some text</div>
    <div>Some text</div><div>Some text</div>
    <div>Some text</div><div>Some text</div>
    <div>Some text</div><div>Some text</div>
    <div>Some text</div><div>Some text</div>
    <div>Some text</div><div>Some text</div>
    <div>Some text</div><div>Some text</div>
    <div>Some text</div><div>Some text</div>
    <div>Some text</div><div>Some text</div>
    <div>Some text</div><div>Some text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks - but flexboxes only seem to work for IE 11 and newer. I would prefer a solution down to approx IE 9. But your approach is very clean and simple!

Comment: @user1863617 There is no solution that will work with a dynamic height on the header without using script for those older browsers. And since the browser statistics is less than 2% on those I just can't see the point.

Comment: @user1863617 With your markup and style structure, to simply let those users get a full page scroll instead, is a really good fallback ... I have the exact same scenario on my own web site and it works like a charm :)